# What is the easiest way to detect whether a user is logged in via google apps marketplace?

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I have a web application which users log into using google oauth2.

I have a google apps marketplace listing for this application, and some portion of the google oauth2 users didn't need to grant permission to my application because their google apps domain administrator did it while installing the apps marketplace listing.

I'd like to be able to detect this second group of users, to analyze how frequently the apps marketplace listing is being used to log into my application. At the moment all google oauth2 logins look the same to my application.

Is there a simple API call I can make to find out whether the current user is in this group?

Comment: I argue maybe there's a way to analyze it by collecting users' login email address to see which domain the user logged in with.    You could find the way to collect login email address from the link: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Comment: Is it then possible to query whether a particular domain installed our listing in the apps marketplace?

Comment: Yes. The customer license API allows you to retrieve the license status of a customer, identified by the customer's domain. You can find more information on this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/v2/developers_guide

Comment: Thanks! Should I be worried about the deprecation warning at the top of that doc? I have a new-style apps marketplace listing.

Comment: You don't have to worry about that and also the API. Refer to the new documentation link for more information. https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your last message?

Comment: So you are worried about the deprecation of old Google apps marketplace, rather than the customer license API, right?

Comment: New listings may only be created using the new version: existing developers may need to create a new Chrome Web Store account to publish new listings. Which version are you using now?

Comment: I'm using the new apps marketplace based on the chrome web store. The deprecation warning at the top of https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/v2/developers_guide makes it look like it only works for the old apps marketplace.

Comment: No, the API works for the new apps marketplace as well.

Comment: Great, thanks, if you feel like making your answer as a stackoverflow "answer", I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, appreciate for that!

Comment: I finally had time to try this. Here is the newest link to the right docs for posterity: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense/get It doesn't work, giving a 403, "Not authorized to access the application ID". I am guessing this is because I'm not the admin of the google apps domain. Does that sound right? Is there an approach which will work for any user, regardless of whether they are the admin of the google apps domain?

Comment: It means the authorized user does not have access to the view (profile). Make sure you are authorized with the correct user and that they indeed have the view (profile) you have selected. See reference here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for finding out marketplace listing info for given appId and target domain:

```
InputStream p12File = Config.class.getResourceAsStream(Config.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY_RESOURCE_PATH);
PrivateKey serviceAccountPrivateKey = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), p12File, "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");

JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpTransport t = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

GoogleCredential.Builder bgc = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(t)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license"))
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(serviceAccountPrivateKey)
            .setServiceAccountId(Config.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID);

GoogleCredential gc = bgc.build();
String token = gc.getAccessToken();
if(token == null) {
  gc.refreshToken();
  token = gc.getAccessToken();
}

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/customerLicense/" + applicationId + "/" + customerDomain);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
// ... read API JSON response
```