# How to tell if user of a Google Drive SDK app installed via Chrome Web Store vs. a user whose domain admin installed it

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

We have an app in both the Chrome web store and the in the Google apps marketplace that interacts with Google Drive.  Under the covers, they are both the same app, even though they are installed from different places.

In the Drive integration settings, we provide a URL to open Drive docs with.  This URL is the same for both drive and apps users.

Is there a way to determine which type of user is hitting that endpoint we provided?  Whether they are working as a user from a Google Apps domain, or if they are a consumer who is working under their own account?

Comment: There's a way to analyze it by collecting users' login email address to see which domain the user logged in with. You could find more details on my reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27048316/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-detect-whether-a-user-is-logged-in-via-google-apps-ma

Comment: Do you use a service account for people who "install" the app?